# How to install windows 7 in a dual-boot pc?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, installation

I have ubuntu 14.04 and windows 7 installed in my pc.Which is a dual-boot system.Now i want to reinstall windows 7 uninstalling both ubuntu and previous windows.How can i do it keeping my personal data safe.Anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Backup the Windows `My Documents` directory (most programs store the data files here).

Backup the Ubuntu `Documents` directory (most programs store the data files here).

You should be ready to reformat your drive.

Answer (score -1):

You will need some sort of storage medium such as a CD, Flash Drive, External Hard Drive (I recommend the latter)

You will need to copy all of your personal files and folders over to your storage medium.

Once done I suggest Installing Windows first and then installing Ubuntu afterwards. The reason for this is because the windows bootloader is temperamental and when installing windows it tends to overwrite the whole HDD which will result in losing everything (in this case your installed Ubuntu).

Summary

1. Backup personal data on a chosen storage Medium
2. Insert Windows disc and do a clean install
3. Install Ubuntu using whatever preferred method you have chosen (CD or USB)